# TypeError list.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi could someone tell me why I am getting the list.map is not a function error?
I don't know why it can't list.map

[image: I don't know why the first 2 lan it is undefined]

below is my code

singleProduct

```
import axiosLink from "../instance/axiosLink";

const SingleProduct = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axiosLink
      .get(`/api/products${id}`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setProduct(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [id]);
  return (
    <div>
      <SingleProductComponent list={product} />
      {/* <RelatedProducts list={product} /> */}
      <Review />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleProduct;
```

SingleProductComponent

```
import React from "react";

const SingleProductComponent = ({ list }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {list &&
        list.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <div className="SingleProduct">
               .........
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleProductComponent;
```

axiosLink

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosLink = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/",
  responseType: "json",
});

export default axiosLink;
```

Can you tell me the reason why? I get this error very often and I don't know the fix yet

this is my api structure

[image: apiFormat]

Comment: `product` is not an array

Comment: You are initialising `product` as an object and then you do `list.map`. Maybe your XHR is returning an array but for first load, product is an Object. So you need to make sure your default values are correct

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize your product state with an array like below

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState([])
```

Comment: i fixed it can you explain me why the first 2 times it doesn't identify

Comment: the first time you are mapping object {}, when you declare object you can not map in Html part that's why it throw error

Answer (score 0):

Check in network (inspect element -> network) if your data is correctly coming to you. Console log your data as well and check if its array. Practically this error says that your "list" is not an array, and it cannot map through it.

Also you should use useEffect(()=>{},[]) so it should fetch your api only once, and initialise your useState for product as empty array [].

Comment: i fixed it can you explain me why the first 2 times it doesn't identify